# How do I break into a running program using gdb?

Tags: gdb

If I run a program under gdb, how do I break at an arbitrary point? Pressing Ctrl+C kills the program. Ctrl+Break does nothing.

I can't enter gdb commands because my program is itself sitting in a REPL loop so anything I enter goes to my program, not to gdb.

My program uses [linenoise](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise) to implement the REPL; I assume that this is hiding Ctrl+C, etc., from gdb.

Ctrl+\ results in a `001C` square blob thingy in my program, rather than SIGUSR1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pressing Ctrl+C kills the program.

That is *not* the default GDB behavior.

Did you set `handle SIGINT nostop pass`?
You can examine current signal disposition with:

```
(gdb) handle SIGINT
Signal        Stop  Print   Pass to program Description
SIGINT        Yes   Yes     No              Interrupt
```

**Update:**

> My program is using linenoise for console input. I assume that it has done something to Ctrl+C

If your program is modifying terminal settings, you are going to have a very bad time debugging it from the *same* terminal.

For example, suppose the program sets `no echo`, and then hits a breakpoint. I *think* you would get a `(gdb)` prompt, but would not see any commands you are typing into GDB.

It seems that you would be much better off debugging this program from a *different* terminal. Use `gdb -p $PID` to attach to it from "outside".

Comment: My program is using [linenoise](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise) for console input. I assume that it has done something to Ctrl+C that means that gdb doesn't see it...?

Comment: But note https://askubuntu.com/questions/41629/after-upgrade-gdb-wont-attach-to-process for attaching to the process.